# How to install multiple nginx ingress controller on bare metal kubernetes cluster

Tags: nginx, kubernetes

Have used the below helm chart for default nginx ingress controller.

helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx 
--repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx 
--namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace

How can i deploy the second ingress controller?

helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx-second ingress-nginx --repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx --namespace ingress-nginx --set controller.ingressClassResource.name=nginx-second

Still my second ingress controller ingress-class is nginx only. Is there any changes need to make in helm chat?

Comment: why not creating them in two separate namespace? `--namespace ingress-nginx-1 --create-namespace` and `--namespace ingress-nginx-2 --create-namespace`

Comment: if you want to use different instances, you need to configure the ingress class with the helm chart deployment. Then you still have to bind the service to two different external ip addresses.